# GUI To Display Scene Graph

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have an implementation question. Before I start, I'm using Qt4 Creator with OpenGL.

So I have this node class, defined like this

```
class node {

private:
    std::vector <node*> leaves;
    node *parent;
    gMatrix3 t;
    polygon *p;

public:
    node()
    void addLeaf(node *n);
    void remove();
    // and other
}
```

I have a class scene defined like this ~

```
private:
    node* root;

public:
    scene();
    node* getRoot();
};
```

The constructor of scene creates a tree of node objects, each of which stores a transformation matrix, a pointer to a polygon, a pointer to its parent node, and a vector of pointers to its children.

Finally, I have a draw function which recursively traverses the tree and calls OpenGL to draw the scene.

So now, I want to build a GUI that gives the user the ability to explicitly add nodes to the graph as a child of any other node, and to remove any leaf node in the structure. I'm vaguely familiar with Qt's TreeWidget class, but I have never used this before and the tutorials on the website are difficult to follow.

Could someone point to in the right direction / suggest any reading material that could get me started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this project, where tree widget has been used extensively.

https://github.com/adnan-kamili/ShareScanner/blob/master/sharescanner.cpp

And this article should act as your base:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html